# Cannot replace `Ụ` with `U` in mysql table

Tags: mysql

This is what I try to do:

```
UPDATE `normal_de` SET `hint_first` = REPLACE(hint_first,'Ụ','U')
```

and result is `0 rows affected` while there is at least one row with this character. Why it is like that?

Comment: What does `select count(*) from normal_de where hint_first like '%Ụ%'` return?

Comment: The following returns `597` which is weird, because there is no such records. I think it takes into consideration also `U` and `Ü` too.

Comment: It works for me : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60b37/1. It doesn't consider `U` as `Ụ`.

Comment: When I select from my table `LIKE %Ụ%` then it returns the onew with `U`. Do not know why:(

Comment: It probably has something to do with collation.

Comment: @ConsiderMe my collation is `utf8_general_ci`. Is it ok?

Comment: Value comparing may vary depending on collations. I do not have enough knowledge to support you in this case, but you may inspect that.

Comment: @ConsiderMe What other collations may work with this? What do you suggest? I will try every of them...

Comment: What I meant is that in some collations `U` may be treated like `Ụ` and in others they vary.

Comment: Pls post your table structure and one line of sample data containing 'Ụ'